# Full height row with bootstrap and sb-admin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the sb-admin theme based on bootstrap:
https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2

I'm trying to create a full height row, but can't figure it out.

Within the body tag, my html looks like this:

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
  </nav>

  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
      </div>

      <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="page-body" style="background: green; height: 100%">Body</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="page-toolbar" style="background: blue; height: 100%">Toolbar</div>
      </div>

      <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>




  </div>
  <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

I've set page-body and page-toolbar to be 100% height, but they don't expand.  I assume they are 100% of their parent.  The question is what do I need to set to get these to fill the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the divs full height of the viewport, you can give

```
height: 100vh;
```

to it. This means 100% height of viewport.

In similar way

```
width: 100vw;
```

can be used for width of viewport. And if you want to be specific about heights. For example if you have a navbar with 75px height and you want the div to cover the remanining area you can use CSS `calc` method and just give it

```
height: calc(100vh - 75px);
```